# Adopt another site's Open Graph properties

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm implementing the Open Graph protocol on my site, and I'm curious if it is possible to "adopt" another site's Open Graph properties within my site's web pages.

For example, suppose a user makes a post to my site that contains a link to an article (such as the New York Times). They then share that post on platforms such as Facebook and Twitter, and I want the preview image on those platforms to contain the Open Graph image from the New York Times article web page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, when the user validates the post, you have to check the links inside to target the link of NYT. Then you have to parse yourself the page of the NYT to return the content you want. And finally you use the informations of the OG Tags of the NYT's page.

I think it's a heavy process, and keep in mind that Google penalize heavily the duplicate content from the others websites.